# Preveng flag.Parse() to swallow the "--"?

Tags: go

Is it possible to prevent `flag.Parse()` from "swallowing" (removing) the `--` from the `flag.Args()`?

## Example

```golang
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    fmt.Println(flag.Args())
}
```

I can't differentiate these 2 invocations:

```sh
$ go run . hello
[hello]

$ go run . -- hello
[hello]
```

## Why would I like to differentiate these 2 invocations?

I'm writing a Go program that **wraps another subprogram**.

My program has some **optional positional args**:

```
myprog [options] [ARG1 ARG2 ...] [-- SUBARG1 SUBARG2...]
```

Invocation examples:

```sh
$ myprog -flag1 val1

$ myprog -flag1 val1 foo
# foo is for myprog

$ myprog -flag1 val1 foo -- bar
# foo is for myprog
# bar is for the subprogram

$ myprog -flag1 val1 -- bar
# bar is normally for the subprogram, BUT flag.Args() = ["bar"] so I have no way to know that it was after "--"
```

I understand that I can use `---` as separator or any other combination, but I was just curious to know for the `--` argument.

## Edit after accepted answer

Source:

```golang
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    var initFlag = flag.Bool("init", false, "init")
    var subArgs []string
    for i := len(os.Args) - 1; i > 0; i-- {
        if os.Args[i] == "--" {
            subArgs = os.Args[i+1:]
            os.Args = os.Args[:i]
            break
        }
    }
    flag.Parse()
    fmt.Println(*initFlag)
    fmt.Println(flag.Args())
    fmt.Println(subArgs)
}
```

All tests succeeded!

```sh
$ go run .
false
[]
[]

$ go run . foo
false
[foo]
[]

$ go run . -- bar
false
[]
[bar]

$ go run . foo -- bar
false
[foo]
[bar]

$ go run . -init foo -- bar
true
[foo]
[bar]

$ go run . -init -- bar
true
[]
[bar]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The flag package does not have an option to disable the flag terminator `--`.

Split the subprogram arguments from the main program arguments before calling `flag.Parse()`:

```
var subArgs []string
for i := len(os.Args) - 1; i > 0; i-- {
    if os.Args[i] == "--" {
        subArgs = os.Args[i+1:]
        os.Args = os.Args[:i]
        break
    }
}
flag.Parse()
```

Comment: While this is correct in general I suspect it will not work with `go run` in particular, because `go run` will not pass the "--" argument on to the compiled program. So use `go build` or `go install` instead.

Comment: @Peter : I did some tests with `go run` and it worked without any trouble.

Answer (score -1):

> Is it possible to prevent flag.Parse() from "swallowing" (removing) the -- from the flag.Args()?

No.

Comment: @StevenPenny Would "No, this is not possible. Package flag provides no such option." Better? The question is a clear yes/no question and the answer is no.